# Multiple rows or column array

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a personal project where I need to be able to store and retrieve game statistics for a bunch of players and support very fast lookup on each player id. My current design (with unnecessary details omitted) looks something along the lines of

```
games: player1's score > player2's score > player3's score > player4's score
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY | player1 VARCHAR(8) | player2 VARCHAR(8) | player3 VARCHAR(8) | player4 VARCHAR(8) |
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1                        | playerA            | playerB            | playerC            | playerD            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1                        | playerE            | playerF            | playerE            | playerA            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1                        | playerF            | playerB            | playerC            | playerE            |
+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

player_games:
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY | player VARCHAR(8) | gameid BIGSERIAL |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 1                     | asdf              | 1                |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 2                     | asdf              | 2                |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 3                     | fdsa              | 1                |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| ...                   | ...               | ...              |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

and I will do a player lookup along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE id IN (SELECT gameid FROM player_games WHERE player='<player>')
```

Since I will be inserting tens of thousands of games per day, I am looking for ways to efficiently store data in `player_games`. The other alternative I am considering is to use an array, so instead we will have something along the lines of

```
player_games:
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
| player VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY | gameids BIGSERIAL[] |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
```

and I will do a lookup with

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE id IN unnest(SELECT gameids FROM player_games WHERE player='<player>')
```

Which option is the better option here, and in the case of the first, is it beneficial to have an index on the `player` column? I will be batch inserting roughly `4000` rows per hour (`90000` rows per day) into `player_games` after populating the historical data.

Comment: I don't understand the design of the games table at the top. Can you give a sample row corresponding to the rows in player_games. How many players participate in a game?

Comment: 3 or 4 players participate per game and have an omitted score column per player. I have also omitted some game metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Given the information in the question I would start out with something like:

```
CREATE TABLE players
( player char(8) not null primary key
, additional attributes );

CREATE TABLE games
( game_id int not null primary key
, additional attributes );

CREATE TABLE player_games (match?)
( player char(8) not null
     references players (player)
, game_id int not null
     references games (game_id)
, participant_no smallint not null
,    constraint ... check (participant_no between 1 and 4)
,    primary key (player, game_id)
,    unique (game_id, participant_no) )

CREATE TABLE results 
( game_id int not null
, player char(8) not null
, score ... not null
,     foreign key (game_id, player)
      references player_games (game_id, player)
```

Example of queries that can easily be answered

Which games has a player participated in?

```
SELECT game_id 
FROM player_games
WHERE player = ?
```

`JOIN` with games if you need more info from each game

Which players participated in a game?

```
SELECT player 
FROM player_games
WHERE game_id = ?
```

`JOIN` with players if you need more info from each player

Order the players from game X according to there score:

```
SELECT player, score
FROM results
WHERE game_id = X
ORDER BY score
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM games
WHERE id IN (SELECT gameid FROM player_games WHERE player='<player>')
```

Just rewrite that as a `JOIN`

```
SELECT games.*
FROM games AS g
JOIN player_games AG pg ON pg.gameid = g.id
WHERE player = $1;
```

If you haven't implemented any of this stuff, as a minor note using `id` is really an anti-pattern and should be avoided as a naming convention. `JOIN`ing on an array is a bad idea. I would leave things the way they are. On the high side, how many games are people playing? Aggregating 10,000 games should be very fast.

> Which option is the better option here, and in the case of the first, is it beneficial to have an index on the player column?

Yes, you need to index the foreign key and the column you're selecting on.

Also, do not use `VARCHAR(8)` for a playerid. You should be using `int` for an id, and something named like `player_username` as a `text` field. In PostgreSQL we *rarely* use `varchar(8)`, as it offers nothing but a length check to slow down what should often times be an unrestricted column.

Even if you were using arrays, you shouldn't be using them like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM games
WHERE id IN unnest(
  SELECT gameids
  FROM player_games
  WHERE player='<player>'
);
```

Instead, write something like this with the containment operator `@>`

```
SELECT *
FROM games AS g
JOIN player_games AS pg ON g.id=pg.gameids
WHERE pg.gameids @> g.id;
```

Or you can use `ANY`,

```
SELECT *
FROM games AS g
JOIN player_games AS pg ON g.id=pg.gameids
WHERE g.id = ANY(pg.gameids);
```

Also may want to look into the `intarray` extension. But, again **I would never do this**.

### Update

I would fix the schema,

```
CREATE SCHEMA local;
CREATE TABLE local.players (
  playerid  int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  .. your profile and stuff, perhaps the login to your own system
);

CREATE SCHEMA thirdparty;
CREATE TABLE thirdparty.username_to_players (
  playerid             int  REFERENCES local.players,
  thirdparty_username  text
);
```

This would make your query look like,

```
SELECT local.games.*
FROM local.games AS lg
-- playerid is your internal player id EVERYWHERE
JOIN player_games AG pg USING (playerid)
JOIN thirdparty.username_to_players AS tpup USING (playerid)
WHERE tpup.thirdparty_username = $1;
```

I would still use `text` there and not `varchar(8)` because why not? If they send a 9 digit player id, you going to call up the provider on the phone and tell them they're breaking the spec -- and, if you do will they likely care? Not worth my time, and I don't particularly care if they lie to me about their schema, I just fast, working, reliable operations. As a third party provider, it's not your duty to ensure their data meets their claims about it.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! Player ids in this case are just player names and the service I am pulling the logs from enforces them to be 8 characters maximum. Should I still be using `text` in this case?

Comment: @incertia see the update.